# Connecting via ssh when building app with Jenkins

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

Tell me please.

I'm using Jenkins to build a project that runs in a docker container and I've run into a problem.

When executing this piece of code:

```
stage('deploy front') {
    when { equals expected: 'do', actual: buildFront }
    agent {docker{image 'ebiwd/alpine-ssh'}}

    steps{
        sh 'chmod 400 .iac/privatekey'
        sh "ssh -i   .iac/privatekey ci_user@134.209.181.163"
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> + ssh -i .iac/privatekey ci_user@134.209.181.163
>
> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>
> Warning: Permanently added '134.209.181.163' (ECDSA) to the list of
> known hosts.
>
> bind: No such file or directory
>
> unix_listener: cannot bind to path:
> /root/.ssh/sockets/ci_user@134.209.181.163-22.uzumQ42Zb6Tcr2E9

Moreover, if you execute the following script with your hands in the container, then everything works

```
ssh -i   .iac/privatekey ci_user@134.209.181.163
```

container with Jenkins started with docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:2.277.1-lts
    container_name: jenkins
    hostname: jenkins
    restart: always
    user: root
    privileged: true

    ports:
      - 172.17.0.1:8070:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker/jenkins/home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error in my Gitlab pipelines:

```
bind: No such file or directory
unix_listener: cannot bind to path: /root/.ssh/sockets/aap_adm@wp-np2-26.ebi.ac.uk-22.LIXMnQy4cW5klzgB
lost connection
```

I think that the error is related to [this changeset](https://github.com/ebiwd/alpine-ssh/commit/868516f6b31b46fd8770bc89066014924f9c4624#diff-56744b58678a7421584a05b2fe5341f5b117e4a21b8b12df1cad23bb13889b9d).

In particular, the ssh config file requires the path "~/.ssh/sockets" to be present. Since we are not using the script /usr/local/bin/add-ssh-key (custom script created for that image) this path is missing.

I've opened an issue in the image project: [Error using the image in CI/CD pipelines #10](https://github.com/ebiwd/alpine-ssh/issues/10).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at this place:

```
agent {docker{image 'ebiwd/alpine-ssh'}}
```

When i change it to prev version, like:

```
agent {docker{image 'ebiwd/alpine-ssh:3.13'}}
```

Everything started working